# SelectedIndexChanged event not firing in child control

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a asp.net control that references a user control(popup) when a button is pressed.  When the button is pressed I find the drop down list in the popup user control and I set the selected value of it.

```
  protected void btnMyBUtton_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        pnlUserControl_ModalPopupExtender.Show();

        if (ddParent.SelectedIndex > 0)
        {
            DropDownList dd = ucMyControl.FindControlRecursive("ddChild") as DropDownList;

            dd.SelectedValue = ddParent.SelectedValue;

        }
    }
```

In the popup user control I'm expecting the SelectedIndexChanged event to fire. However, it isn't.  Any ideas why this would be the case?

Markup for my child control(only relevant code) is below:

```
<asp:FormView ID="myForm" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsMyDS" DefaultMode="Insert">
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:Panel runat="server">
        <table>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label Text="Name" runat="server" /></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddChild" runat="server" DataSourceID="ddDS" DataMember="" DataValueField="Id" DataTextField="Name" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Id") %>' AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddChild_SelectedIndexChanged" OnDataBound="ddChild_DataBound" />
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="btInsertOk" runat="server" Text="Add" CommandName="Insert" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btInsertCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </asp:Panel>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must associate the event handling method to the new dd control. E.g. dd.SelectedIndexChanged += 
   new System.EventHandler(ddChild_SelectedIndexChanged);

Comment: @GrantWinney according to my understanding ddChild is the one having the event attached. But, dd is a new control, right? Will it fire ddChild's SelectedIndexChanged event indirectly without wiring it up?

Comment: The only place I have it wired up is in my markup on the actual drop down list in my child control

Comment: @GrantWinney I've added some markup code for the child control.  Let me know if that helps.

Comment: @GrantWinney yes, you are correct 'dd' is same as 'ddChild'. SelectedIndexChanged event is bit confusing. According to 'MSDN' the definition for this method is "Occurs when the selection from the list control changes between posts to the server." So, this event fires in the next postback in AspUser7724. I did littlebit of testing and this is true. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You can force the event by calling the event as a method like ddChild_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, args);

Comment: @Sam Since it is protected am I still able to call it like a method?

Comment: If it's in a user control no. Otherwise yes. Extract your SelectedIndexChanged functionality into a public method and call that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the event doesn't fire when changing the selected value in the code-behind. It only fires when the user changes the value by selecting a new value in the drop-down.

What you could do, is move your code out of the event into a separate method, and call that method from the event. Your event will still fire when the user makes a change via the UI.

```
protected void ddChild_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ImportantStuff();
}

public void ImportantStuff()
{
    // everything that was in the SelectedIndexChanged event
}
```

Then in your button click event, store the old `SelectedIndex` value, make the change, and compare it to the new `SelectedIndex` value. If they're different, then the selected index has changed, and you can call the same method being called by the `SelectedIndexChanged` event above:

```
protected void btnMyBUtton_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    pnlUserControl_ModalPopupExtender.Show();

    if (ddParent.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        DropDownList dd = ucMyControl.FindControlRecursive("ddChild") as DropDownList;

        var oldIndex = dd.SelectedIndex;

        dd.SelectedValue = ddParent.SelectedValue;

        var newIndex = dd.SelectedIndex;

        if (oldIndex != newIndex)  // selected index changed
            ImportantStuff();
    }
}
```

As Sam noted, the `ImportantStuff()` method should be public in the UserControl, so you can access it from the Page the UserControl is in.

Better yet, assuming the "important stuff" doesn't need to access other controls in the UserControl, you could move that code into a separate class, and then call it from both places without requiring a Page to call public methods in the UserControl (your code stays a little bit cleaner, and less tangled up).

Comment: Yes, this is a good solution. But, ImportantStuff() should be public as I believe ddChild control is in a user control. Therefore, it should be called as ucMyControl.ImportantStuff();

Answer (score 0):

`SelectedIndexChanged` event is bit confusing. According to `MSDN` the definition for this method is

> Occurs when the selection from the list control changes between posts
>   to the server.

**So, this event fires in the next postback** in this case (since there's no `AutoPostback`) even if you don't select anything from the DropDownList. This is because the selected index has changed between the postbacks. Not sure whether this is a bug. I did little bit of testing and this is true. Correct me if I'm wrong. I learnt something new today :)

**Solution**

The solution to the problem is what @GrantWinney suggested. Extract the common functionality in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event into a public event and call that method just after the following line.

```
dd.SelectedValue = ddParent.SelectedValue;
```

If your ddChild control was in the same method you could just invoke it's `SelectedIndexChanged` event by calling it as follows

```
ddChild_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, args);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are showing your  user control  in ajax popup. You might try popping up your usercontrol like this:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pseudopopup" runat="server" visible="false">
 <table style="position: fixed; z-index: 1; left: 0px; top: 0px"   border="0"  width="100%" height="100%">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top"  align="center"  >
        <div style="margin:top:60px; width:600px" class="shadow"
        <ascx:WebUserControl ID="mycontrol" runat="server" />   
        </div> 
        </td>        
    </tr>
    </table> 
 </asp:Panel>
```

In code behind:

```
protected void btnMyBUtton_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
pseudopopup.Visible = true;
```